# What is the difference between a stream and a file?

Tags: c, file, io, stream

The C standard talks about streams. For example the [`fopen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) manual page tells that `fopen` is a *stream open function*.

Can anybody explain what exactly *streams* are, and how they relate to *files*?

Comment: What is your understanding till time? Did you though of using google?

Comment: Can you provide context for that quote? It is unclear what it is referring to; if you read it in a book, more context may help us clarify it better.

Comment: Not all files have same capabilities. For example, a disk file can support random access, while some printers cannot.

Comment: Who is "you" in the context "what you mean..."?

Comment: Here is the link I found useful: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/924dfa2e-62c1-4c5c-b1ef-04b0d0a3550f/difference-between-file-and-stream?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the context of the C Standard Library a stream is a generic interface for performing certain I/O operations. You can read from streams, write to streams, some streams are seekable. Opening a file as a stream is only one way to get a stream as an I/O interface for an application.

[Let me quote:](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Streams-and-File-Descriptors)

> **11.1.1 Streams and File Descriptors**
>
> When you want to do input or output to a file, you have a choice of two basic mechanisms for representing the connection between your program and the file: file descriptors and streams. File descriptors are represented as objects of type `int`, while streams are represented as `FILE *` objects.
>
> File descriptors provide a primitive, low-level interface to input and output operations. Both file descriptors and streams can represent a connection to a device (such as a terminal), or a pipe or socket for communicating with another process, as well as a normal file. [...]

[... and further:](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Streams)

> **12.1 Streams**
>
> For historical reasons, the type of the C data structure that represents a stream is called `FILE` rather than “stream”. Since most of the library functions deal with objects of type `FILE *`, sometimes the term *file pointer* is also used to mean “stream”. This leads to unfortunate confusion over terminology in many books on C.

Examples for I/O streams in C:

- **Standard Streams:** https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdin
- **File Streams:** https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen
- **Pipes:** https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen
- **Stream Sockets:** https://linux.die.net/man/2/socket

For further reading, also have a look at these links:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#I_002fO-Overview
- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#I_002fO-on-Streams

The stream-based API is built on top of the low-level *file descriptor* API and provides additional functionality. Some low-level features are however only available via the lower level API, e.g., *memory-mapped I/O*, *non-blocking I/O* or "event-driven" I/O:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html
- https://linux.die.net/man/2/poll
- https://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll